# Deploy Jekyll project without a webserver

Tags: deployment, webserver, jekyll

I created a blog with Jekyll and now I need to deploy it and send it to a person that need to navigate it without a web server. So, I entered `jekyll build` from terminal and get the compiled project in `_site`. But now, if I open index.html it doesn't get the assets (CSS). In the head tag tag there's `/css/main.css` while I need `css/main.css` (no initial slash). I don't want to change manually the url, so I'm asking if there's a way to deploy a Jakyll project for showing in local without webserver.

Comment: So you're looking for a way to serve static files without any webserver at all? I don't think this is specific to Jekyll, and couldn't be done without changing the url (since you mentioned you don't want that), you can use a different local webserver to just serve the files, like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server that way your client doesn't need to install jekyll, or use a free webhost like 000, or github for them to see (but this is 'public'). If this works I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is possible only if you know where, in the file system, it will be deployed.

Examples :

#### Linux

For a deployment in `/home/user/www`, go in `_config.yml` and set `baseurl: /home/user/www`

#### Windows

For a deployment in `C:/Users/Toto/www`, go in `_config.yml` and set `baseurl: /C:/Users/Toto/www`

Deployment means copying `generated files` in the target folder, **not** copying the `_site` folder.

Do a `jekyll build` and send you files with deploy instructions.

**Edit:**

This answer is for you, not the client.

As you client is certainly running windows, you just set your `baseurl: /C:/_site`, zip the `_site` folder and ask the client to unzip in `C:/`.

The client will just have to click on `C:/_site/index.html` to start the site in his default browser.

Comment: I appreciate your contribute but I was asking for a way to do that without manual editing (for avoiding complication for the client)

Answer (score 0):

Change the assets directory to relative paths such as: **assets/css/**.
This will work on a server or locally.

Set a page variable to represent the nesting in your Yaml front matter. Then, append that variable to your assets.

```
---
layout: default
title: Nested Page
path: ../
---
```

or

```
---
layout: default
title: Root level page
path: ""
---

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ page.path }}assets/stylesheets/style.css">
```